# Upgraded Eleastic Search via Brew - now won't start with Unrecognized VM option 'UseConcMarkSweepGC' error

Tags: elasticsearch, homebrew, searchkick

Was troubleshooting ES and figured I would try and upgrade to 7.10.2:

```
Dans-MacBook-Pro:~ aximus$ brew services restart elasticsearch
Stopping `elasticsearch`... (might take a while)
==> Successfully stopped `elasticsearch` (label: homebrew.mxcl.elasticsearch)
==> Successfully started `elasticsearch` (label: homebrew.mxcl.elasticsearch)
```

The start-up fails:

```
Dans-MacBook-Pro:~ aximus$ tail -f /usr/local/var/log/elasticsearch.log

    error:
    Unrecognized VM option 'UseConcMarkSweepGC'
    Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
    Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.
        at org.elasticsearch.tools.launchers.JvmErgonomics.flagsFinal(JvmErgonomics.java:126)
        at org.elasticsearch.tools.launchers.JvmErgonomics.finalJvmOptions(JvmErgonomics.java:88)
        at org.elasticsearch.tools.launchers.JvmErgonomics.choose(JvmErgonomics.java:59)
        at org.elasticsearch.tools.launchers.JvmOptionsParser.jvmOptions(JvmOptionsParser.java:137)
        at org.elasticsearch.tools.launchers.JvmOptionsParser.main(JvmOptionsParser.java:95)
```

I have tried to re-install and link openjdk@11 (11.0.10) with no success. Currently dead in the water:

```
Dans-MacBook-Pro:~ aximus$ curl 127.0.0.1:9200
curl: (7) Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1 port 9200: Connection refused
```

Answer (score 8):

Stumbled across a related issue and realized that this was in my `/usr/local/etc/elasticsearch/jvm.options` file:

```
## GC configuration
#-XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC
#-XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=75
#-XX:+UseCMSInitiatingOccupancyOnly
```

Commented these out and now it's all good

Comment: Thanks . It works for me on my MacOS  Monterey